# Pandas insert a blank row after each row in Excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel

New to Pandas firstly. I am using the following code to write to an Excel file using Pandas. Please see the line `worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)`. Question is, how can I insert a blank row after each row. For instance I want something like

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4   (This is the Header)
--------------Blank row
C1    C2   C3   C4
--------------Blank row
C1    C2   C3   C4
--------------Blank row
C1    C2   C3   C4
```

This is what I have

```
def create_excel_with_format(headers,values,full_file_name_with_path):
   
   df = pd.DataFrame(data=values,columns=headers)
   with pd.ExcelWriter(full_file_name_with_path) as writer:
       df.to_excel(writer, index=False)

   workbook  = writer.book
   worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
   #font_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 10})
   header_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': False,
        'border': False,
        'text_wrap': True})
   
   for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

   font_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 13})
   worksheet.set_row(0, None, font_fmt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `df` a has default index (*range of integers starting at 0*) , you can use :

```
out = df.set_axis(df.index*2 + 1).reindex(range(len(df)*2))
```

Also, there is an *indentation-problem* with the bloc inside the context manager :

```
def create_excel_with_format(headers,values,full_file_name_with_path):
   
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=values,columns=headers)
    df = df.set_axis(df.index*2 + 1).reindex(range(len(df)*2))
    
    with pd.ExcelWriter(full_file_name_with_path) as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, index=False)

        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

        header_format = workbook.add_format({
            'bold': False,
            'border': False,
            'text_wrap': True})

        for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
            worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

        font_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 13})
        worksheet.set_row(0, None, font_fmt)
```

Output (*in Excel*) :

[image]

Used call :

```
values = [
    ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'],
    ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'],
    ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']
]

headers= ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4']

create_excel_with_format(headers, values, "file.xlsx")
```